# Cannot Use Frameworks added via Cocoapods in Release Build

Tags: ios, cocoapods, xcode7

In my project, I have added my dependencies via Cocoapods. For this question, I am using CocoaAsyncSocket as an example, but I have the same issue the two other dependencies that I am using. My Podfile looks like:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

link_with 'MainTarget'

pod 'CocoaLumberjack'
pod 'CocoaAsyncSocket'
pod 'SVProgressHUD'

target 'MainTargetTests' do
    pod 'OCMock', '~> 3.0'
end
```

Everything works as expected when I build and run the application in debug (on a device). When I archive the app (with an enterprise license), I can not create a new instance of GCDAsyncSocket. There no compiler or linker errors, and I when look into the contents of the .ipa, and all frameworks are packaged as expected.

An example of the behaviour:

```
@implementation OPTAppDelegate
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    [self configSocketManager];

    // perform the rest of the usual set up.
    return YES;
}

- (void) configSocketManager {
    GCDAsyncSocket *socket = [[GCDAsyncSocket alloc] init];
    if ( ! socket ) {
        // we only enter this block in when the app is built for release
        [[NSException exceptionWithName:@"Socket Not Created" reason:@"No idea" userInfo:nil] raise];
    }

    // if we get here, all is good
}
```

Some Environment Info:
- Xcode Version 7.1.1
- Cocapods Version 0.39.0

Pod install Output:

```
Updating local specs repositories
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Installing CocoaAsyncSocket (7.4.2)
Installing CocoaLumberjack (2.2.0)
Installing OCMock (3.2)
Installing SVProgressHUD (1.1.3)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Sending stats
Sending stats
Pod installation complete! There are 4 dependencies from the Podfile and 4 total pods installed.
```

The workspace is created as expected, and I am not modifying any other build settings,not any of the build phases.

#### What could be preventing the use of the above frameworks in a release build?

SVProgressHUD and CocoaLumberjack become equally useless.

#### UPDATE Jan. 4, 2016:

Using the hints provided by the [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34423692/620197), it has fixed a crash, but it seems whenever I try to instantiate an object (i.e. GCDAsyncSocket), it returns `nil`.

Comment: `use_frameworks!` do you need that?

Comment: @orkoden For this case, no. It turns out I can remove that line and build the dependencies as static libraries. But doesn't that defeat the purpose of using frameworks?

Answer (score 1):

From what I read in the past few weeks with similar issues, you cannot do a combination of

```
// Method 1
pod '1'
pod '2'

// Method 2
target 'MainTargetTests' do
    pod '3', '~> 3.0'
end
```

Try to stick with one method, or the other. If you need common pods, since it's basically a ruby file you can declare something like :

```
def common_pods
  pod '1'
  pod '2'
end

target 'Debug' do
  common_pods
end

target 'Release' do
  common_pods
  pod '3'
end
```

Hope that helps! That way you can also remove your 'linked_with'

Comment: This helped to fix a crash on start up, but now, it seems CFNetwork is not available, since I can not make a socket connection.